# ERROR (100) : Parameters do not match any fields that can be updated

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

I am trying to post Facebook Page status as page(not user) through my script. This returns me an error 100.

Here I am generating temporary user_access_token from Graph Explorer with permission : manage_pages, publish_pages

#### Code:

```
<?php
    $url='https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/{$user_id}/accounts?access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN';
    $ch=curl_init();
    CURL_SETOPT($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    CURL_SETOPT($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $json=json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
    
    $page_access_token=$json->data['0']->access_token;
    curl_close($ch);

    $page_id='xxx';
    $message='helloworld';
    $url="https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/{$page_id}?access_token=$page_access_token"; 
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $message);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

    $result = json_decode(curl_exec($curl));
    var_dump($result);

 ?>
```

If everything goes well, a string "helloworld" should get posted on Facebook page. But here it is returning with an error :

```
object(stdClass)#5 (1) {
  ["error"]=>
  object(stdClass)#6 (3) {
    ["message"]=>
    string(61) "(#100) Parameters do not match any fields that can be updated"
    ["type"]=>
    string(14) "OAuthException"
    ["code"]=>
    int(100)
  }
}
```

What is mistake here ? Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're trying to post to `/<PAGE_ID>`

The correct endpoint for creating a post on a Page is `/<PAGE_ID>/feed`, documented here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/page/feed

A valid format for a basic call to create a post would be `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/<PAGE_ID>/feed?message=helloworld&access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>`